# unable to match value using indexof

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array picked from a google spreadsheets.

Now I have a single object from a different array arr[0][0] which is equal to an element present in the main array `data`.

Here is my code:-

```
function userClickedComp(arr)
{
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KtCHHj7CwXe6EOyMp_CgLAy2xFhOX2QrzyWetELhPMc');
  var name = "L.Balance."+year;
  var sheet1 = ss2.getSheetByName(name);
  var lastrow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet1.getRange("A1:A"+lastrow).getValues();
  
  var pos = data.indexOf(arr[0][0]);
  console.log(data+"......."+arr[0][0]+"........"+pos)
}
```

Here is my console.
[image]

As you can see its giving me -1 but the matching value exists in the array.

Comment: What does `console.log(data,".......",arr[0][0],"........",pos)` say?

Comment: What's in arr[0][0] ? object or string ?

Comment: its there in the image "supreet" and "-1"

Comment: `pos = "-1"` and `arr[0][0] = "supreetsingh"`

Comment: Can you help with dummy data in the same format , so that community here can help in better way ? Better create a sandbox and share.